# How to show camera captured image in uitableview with textfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have captured an image and saved it to the document directory, now I want to show those captured images in `UiTableView` at runtime. Whenever I capture an image, it has to show in a `UiTableView`. Every time I want to create a new row with the captured image and show a `TextView` next to the image to make a note about the captured image.

Answer (score 1):

Create UITableViewCell which is having one UIImageView and UITextField near to it. Register NSNotification. After saving the captured image in doocument directory,post notification and reload table.